# Trying to remove items from list of strings but get the error list.remove(x): x not in list

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I'm trying to write a function that returns a list of the three most frequent words in a string but I get the following error when I try to remove unwanted punctuation from the string "list.remove(x): x not in list"

As an example, "//wont won't won't " should return  ["won't", "wont"] or "a a a  b  c c  d d d d  e e e e e" should return ["e", "d", "a"] Any ideas?

```
def top_3_words(text):
    
    new_list = []
    
    new_text = text.lower().split()
    
    for word in new_text:
        for char in word:
            if char.isalpha():
                pass   
            else:
                new_text.remove(char)
             


    Count = Counter(new_text)
    most_occur = Count.most_common(3)
    
    for l in most_occur:
        new_list.append(l[0])
    
    return new_list
```

Comment: your output is not clear, write it out more clearly.

Comment: `new_text` is a list `["//wont", "won't", "won't"]`, you can remove elements only when they are present in your list. In you case the elements are `"//wont"` and `"won't"`. But you are trying to remove a character of an element present in your list from the list i.e `"/"` Which is incorrect. Hence, getting error: "list.remove(x): x not in list"

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems. 1. You need to replace a character in a string with '' if you want to remove it. 2. Your Counter is still pointed to your new_text list and not your stripped words.  Finally, calling isalpha on each character will get rid of the apostrophe in "won't", which I assume you don't want.  Here is a different approach.  You can chain as many .replace statements as you need to get rid of all unwanted punctuation.

```
from collections import Counter
def top_3_words(text):
    new_list = []
    new_text = text.lower().split()
    stripped_words = []

    for word in new_text:
        word = word.replace('/','')
        stripped_words.append(word)

    Count = Counter(stripped_words)
    most_occur = Count.most_common(3)

    for l in most_occur:
        new_list.append(l[0])

    return new_list

print(top_3_words("//wont won't won't "  ))
print(top_3_words("a a a b c c d d d d e e e e e"))

#output:
["won't", 'wont']
['e', 'd', 'a']
```

More generally, you can create a list of unwanted punctuation and iterate through it as follows:

```
unwanted = ['.','/',';',':',',']
stripped_words = []

for word in new_text:
    for punc in unwanted:
        word = word.replace(punc, '')
    stripped_words.append(word)

...
print(top_3_words("//wo;nt wo:n't won't... "  ))
#output: ["won't", 'wont']
```

Comment: That fixed the problem with the //won't but I want it to work for removing other punctuation as well. Ex: "  , e   .. " should only return  ["e"]

Comment: As I said before, you can chain as many replace methods as you want to get rid of all unwanted punctuation and keep the wanted punctuation. For example, to also get rid of periods, you do: word = word.replace('/','').replace('.','')

Answer (score 0):

Be careful because you are trying to remove `char` from `new_text` but char is a character from the string `word`.

If you want to remove the unwanted character you can do the following:
Instead of using

```
new_text.remove(char)
```

You can use

```
word = word.replace(char, '')
```

What this code does is replacing you unwanted character for an empty string.

Another problem you have is that the The *'* will return False in `char.isalpha()` so "won't" will be converted to "wont" and from
"//wont won't won't " you will only get ["wont"]

If what you want is remove the word with an unwanted character, you have to use:

```
 new_text.remove(word)
 break
```

Comment: Hi, this won’t work. new_text is a list, not a string.